# Парсинг таблицы сайта

Tags: python, парсер, веб-сайт

Не могу разобраться, как можно спарсить таблицу на этом сайте https://coronavirus-graph.ru/rossiya/moskva
Дело в том, что я хочу создать список, в котором будет отображаться статистика по дням: Дата, Заражений всего,  Умерло, всего, Летальность, Выздоровело всего,  Болеющих

[image: собственно здесь я все это ищу]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://coronavirus-graph.ru/rossiya/moskva'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='stat_table_box')
    people = []
    for item in items:
        people.append({
            'title': item.find('tbody') .get_text()
        })
        print(people)



def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Answer (score 1):

Если использование BeautifulSoup не есть принципиальным, то можно использовать pandas, который как раз для этого и предназначен (и не только). И код прям в две строки

```
>>> import pandas
>>> ds = pandas.read_html("https://coronavirus-graph.ru/rossiya/moskva")
>>> ds
[           Дата  Заражений всего Умерло всего Летальность  Выздоровело всего       Болеющих
0      4 ноября      18433626305      3172897       0.05%        16186246633   ➜193 010-425
1      3 ноября      18370576827      3163195       0.05%        16119916628   ➜193 435+104
2      2 ноября      18302305736      3153698       0.05%        16053636359   ➜193 331-721
3      1 ноября      18244947103      3143896       0.05%        15990045257  ➜194 052+1750
4    31 октября      18173917603      3134294       0.05%        15937475050  ➜192 302+2459
..          ...              ...          ...         ...                ...            ...
594    20 марта            13133            —           —                  1        ➜130+33
595    19 марта             9812            —           —                  1         ➜97+12
596    18 марта             8631            —           —                  1         ➜85+31
597    17 марта              551            —           —                  1          ➜54+1
598    16 марта             5420            —           —                  1         ➜53+20

[599 rows x 6 columns]]
```

а теперь эти все данные уже находятся в удобной структуре и с ними можно делать все, что угодно. А если почитать [документацию на pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#min), то будет просто чудесно.

Comment: Ого, спасибо вам большое, надо обязательно чекнуть